# Can you type check the function signatures in the return value of mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, flowtype

I am trying to get the function signature of my action creators validated by flow. The prop existing and being a function is being validated but not the function signature.

```
function TrainButtonCmpt({createTrain}: {createTrain: (trainName: string) => void}) {
  const creator = () => { createTrain('Choo choo') }
  return <button onclick="creator()">Create Train</button>
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: *) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    createTrain
  },
  dispatch)
}

function mapStateToProps(state: State) { return {} }

const TrainButton = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TrainButtonCmpt)

export function Test() {
  return <TrainButton />
}
```

With the above example removing `createTrain` from `mapDispatchToProps` causes the `Test` component to fail validation as expected. However when the function signature of `createTrain` doesn't match `(trainName: string) => void` it still passes validation.

Comment: Based on Flow Try your typing of TrainButtonCmpt should fail on another signature than string, check: https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTMBXAOw2AmrgBUoVhqAhSmGBgYXAwAYmwA2SACYAKAN5oiKGEhZtqAXwBccOQqUr2WqTFbsAcihBItAZ2PsA5gEo4AXgB8cAG4RgEtc5lSODg0BlsQ3WhXOClnd20I1D0TaikARgAmAGZnNSC4IhhKKEYAHgAjbl5GBjRRYDQAaxcAInkk6FiWtz5dJGYU0oB6Sp4GN1I8iho6BgHVLjHqATAYADUUeukdJOUUzW12xT3VQ2NVc0sbO2onVw9vX39tfNDqcKPeKGjY+4TPk7sKT4PgACwgEBC4Ig+Fy+UKxTKo2qcFq9SarU+nUc3V6u3m7GGyPGk1IQA.

Comment: @Xarvalus not what I am asking. I want the createTrain function signature passed into the component validated by flow. For example I would like flow to throw an error if I passed `TrainButtonCmpt` `(trainName: number) => {}`

Comment: It should be possible https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChS0IA7AZ3jBzBoDEVgAbJAEzgF44A3qThw0RFDCQAVKGyoAuOAAoYs4FQByKEEkVUAriABGSKAEpFANwjAevAHxx9VLkkzruAGlIBfcpVp6RhoAZX00NCQaGj5BYVFxSRk5RRU1TW1dODoodQBzCzhrWz5HZ1d3Ki9fckxnDGBqOGT1ACF9GBhqAGFwGCUBMVQk9J9FQcTpdNTVOS0dRRz8s1Kimy4fFaERALoE4ehYpRWHQX2JKbklfG6ACwgIUXuIfBW-ESIYfSgqOAAeIwdLq-ahodjANAAa14ACIhhJoMcYfZupNmuk-gB6QGdaj2GqkFpUdq4qi9MD9BgQJisDjcMyE9Ik4HkynBMIRKI0BlAA but depends on typing of the 3rd party libraries (Redux's `connect` etc).